# Link line endpoints to objects in Apple Motion5

Tags: motion, apple

I would like to draw a line between two circles. The endpoints of the line have to be linked each to one circle. When I move one circle the line should automatically expand to keep the connection.

Is this possible with Apple Motion5 (because I already have Motion5)?